# How do I move the origin to the center of the object

Tags: mesh

I just can't manage to make the cursor and origin in the picture to go to the centre of my mesh, I press all the option on shift+s and nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Open your toolbar by pressing 'T', and with the geometry selected, choose: "set origin to geometry".